# Calling the system time in on the Windows 10 IOT on Raspberry PI3

Tags: string, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, systemtime, real-time-clock

My project takes pictures and I'm looking to set the image file names as the time and date they were taken.

I've programmed the camera and set up the real time clock and they both work. However, I'm now struggling to link the two.

Is there a method of returning the system time as as string?
Or anything else I may not have considered?

I used this guide for the RTC : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113626/Adding-the-Missing-Real-Time-Clock-to-Windows-IoT

Comment: `time()` + `strftime()` may work.

Comment: Cant say that worked

Comment: What do you mean by *Cant say that worked*?

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: *it didn't work* is not a problem statement. How *exactly* didn't it work?

Comment: There are not methods within anything I'm using. I'm using VS to write my classes and time() and strftime() are not used in the guide for the RTC or else where

Answer (score 1):

If you get RTC work like this guide state:

> getting Windows IoT to initialize its clock from RTC at bootup so that
>   other solutions don't need to be modified to read from the RTC
>   directly.

You can use the following code line to get system time as a string:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString()
```